# How to list video/audio using webtorrent?

Tags: javascript, webtorrent

When using [webtorrent](https://webtorrent.io/), is there way to list only video/audio from file list.

when there is 3 file in torrent.

```
1. something.mp4
2. something.txt
3. something.mp3
```

I need show file 1 and 3 only, but not 2

Comment: Show us what you have so far, or whatever example you're working from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the files by extension. However what do you mean by "showing" a file? Are you using `file.appendTo()`?